# 'vm.max_map_count is too low' in kubernetes mongodb client

Tags: kubernetes, mongodb

This is how I'm running a mongodb client in my kubernetes cluster:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongodb-client
  namespace: backup
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mongodb-client
      image: mongo:6.0.6
      command: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Then I'm trying to log into the db:

```
mongosh --host "mongodb-0.mongodb-headless.databases.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongodb-1.mongodb-headless.databases.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongodb-2.mongodb-headless.databases.svc.cluster.local:27017" --authenticationDatabase admin -u user
```

I do get the output:

```
Connecting to:          mongodb://<credentials>@mongodb-0.mongodb-headless.databases.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongodb-1.mongodb-headless.databases.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongodb-2.mongodb-headless.databases.svc.cluster.local:27017/?authSource=admin&appName=mongosh+1.10.0
Using MongoDB:          6.0.6
Using Mongosh:          1.10.0

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/


To help improve our products, anonymous usage data is collected and sent to MongoDB periodically (https://www.mongodb.com/legal/privacy-policy).
You can opt-out by running the disableTelemetry() command.

------
  The server generated these startup warnings when booting
  2023-07-11T08:35:10.635+00:00: vm.max_map_count is too low
------
```

Why do I get `vm.max_map_count is too low` and where do I have to configure the value?

Answer (score 0):

This is an operating system knob that you should change. Reviewing the full `mongod` logs may be helpful here.

See the [MongoDB production notes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-checklist-operations/#linux) for more info on the recommended setting for this configuration. More details on why this is required can be found [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-51233).